# gitea action creates a container outside my network

Tags: docker, gitea

I'm having a problem running the gitea actions.

Problem:
I have a network (network1) where I have included the nginx container, the gitea container and the runner container.

I configured a workflow, the problem is that to run this workflow the action creates a container that does not belong to network1, when connecting to gitea says "fatal: unable to access 'http://xxx.xxx.xx.x:xxx/': Failed to connect to xxx.xxx.xx.x:xxx port xxx: Connection timed out"

does anyone have any idea how to solve this?

thanks

```
name: Gitea Actions Demo
run-name: ${{ gitea.actor }} is testing out Gitea Actions 
on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - develop

jobs:
  Explore-Gitea-Actions:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    container:
      image: node:16-bullseye
    steps:
      - run: echo " The job was automatically triggered by a ${{ gitea.event_name }} event."
      - run: echo " This job is now running on a ${{ runner.os }} server hosted by Gitea!"
      - run: echo " The name of your branch is ${{ gitea.ref }} and your repository is ${{ gitea.repository }}."
      - run: echo "Here is the token ${{ gitea.token }}."
      - name: Check out repository code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - run: echo " The ${{ gitea.repository }} repository has been cloned to the runner."
      - run: echo "️ The workflow is now ready to test your code on the runner."
      - name: List files in the repository
        run: |
          ls ${{ gitea.workspace }}          
      - run: echo " This job's status is ${{ job.status }}."
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and I adjusted the `config.yaml` of the runner to use this setting:

```
container:
  # Specifies the network to which the container will connect.
  # Could be host, bridge or the name of a custom network.
  # If it's empty, act_runner will create a network automatically.
  network: "host"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).